# fix container on desktop (992px and up)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to set the container to a fixed size?

When the browser has a certain size I don't want bootstrap to fiddle with container width..

If the browser window is less than 1000px the container is downsized in width so it fits the window. I don't want that..

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
        @media (max-width:768px) {

        }
        @media (min-width:768px) {

        }
        @media (min-width:992px) {
            .container {
                width:1000px;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width:1200px) {
            .container {
                width:1000px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: try max-width:1000px

Comment: It doesn't work.. If the window is resized the container is resized too

Comment: do you verify that the style is applicated to the element by using elemnt inspector ? Or does it get overridden maybe, or not applyed at all

Comment: The width is overwritten by boostrap or never applied

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [boostrap customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to set the container widths to be whatever you want. It will generate you a custom version of the CSS so you don't have to change it manually.

Take a look here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes

Comment: I use boostrap from a CDN

Comment: @clarkk Customization and shared CDNs don't mix well.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your media queries after bootstrap so your element is overwritten.

Comment: The media queries are added after the boostrap `<link>`

Comment: Have you tried !important? Not the best practice but just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

i think youre problem is that youre using less syntax, simply change to standard mediaquery like ::

```
 @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 9999px){
        .container {
            max-width:1000px;
            width:1000px;
            min-width:1000px
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works better.. but is still downsize the width of the container when the browser width is less than 1000px

Comment: have a look at my edit, max-width is only for not getting bigger than 1000px, for not getting smaller than 1000px i added min-width